# How to return multiple columns from one table?

Tags: mysql

How do i return multiple columns from a table ?

My Course table:

> | Course | PersId | Taskid | Status |
>
> Computer < > User1 <> 1 < > confirmed
>   Computer < >User2 <> 1 <> unconfirmed
>  
>   Computer < >User3 <> 1 <> unconfirmed
>  
>   Computer < >User1 <> 2 <> confirmed
>  
>   Computer < >User2 <> 2 <> confirmed
>  
>   Computer < >User3 <> 2 <> unconfirmed

I want it to return like this:

> | PersId | Task_1 | Task_2 |
>
> User1 <> confirmed < > confirmed
>  
>   User2 <> unconfirmed <> confirmed
>  
>   User3 <> unconfirmed <> unconfirmed

Question 2:
 There are other courses(math, english etc) in my table with more tasks than two. Do i need to use some kind of iteration to return the task columns ? because i dont want to make a SQL query for each single course(over 100).

thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! ive updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` and an aggregate:

```
select persid,
  max(case when taskid = 1 then status end) as Task1,
  max(case when taskid = 2 then status end) as Task2
from course
group by persid
```

If you want to include the course info:

```
select persid,
  course,
  max(case when taskid = '1' then status end) as Task1,
  max(case when taskid = '2' then status end) as Task2
from course
group by persid, course
order by course, persid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87c3e/3)

If you have an unknown number of tasks, then you can use a [prepared statement](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) to generate this dynamically:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when taskid = ''',
      taskid,
      ''' then status end) AS Task_',
      taskid
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM course;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT persid, course, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM course 
                  group by persid, course
                  order by course, persid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3769f/1)

Comment: do i have to add the other course's task manually ? is there no iteration i can use that do that for me ? because i have a course with +40 tasks, and most of the course dont have the same amount of courses.

Comment: @user1693991 see my final query, it will generate the sql dynamically so you will not have to hard-code any values.

Comment: is it possible to use this query in csharp ? because it isnt working, the other one worked.

Comment: @user1693991 I am not sure how you would use this in c#, you would have to test it.

Comment: i want to use this query to return a datatable. then use datagridview.datasource

Comment: @user1693991 I am sure you can return the results with c#, I don't have a way of testing that at this moment though.  You will have to try it.

Comment: i tried the previous one on microsoft access2007 but it didnt work, im using access to test it first before implementing on csharp.

Comment: @user1693991 Ms Access has completely different syntax. You tagged your question as MySQL, what database are you using?

Comment: phpMyAdmin

Sorry for asking so many questions, but im a beginner at this.

Comment: The query works for MySQL which is what you requested, I don't know how to implement it in c#, you will have to test it.  As far as in MS Access the syntax is totally different.

Comment: @user1693991 my suggestion would be if you have issues implementing this in c# then consider posting a new question. :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but i think i cant use the prepare statement in csharp, are there other ways to do it in MySQL ?

Comment: not dynamically there are no ways to do expect with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  PersId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Taskid = 1 THEN Status END) AS Task_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Taskid = 2 THEN Status END) AS Task_2
FROM Courses
GROUP BY persID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use power of PIVOTE man

PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.

```
SELECT Course, PersId, [1] AS [Task_1], [2] AS [Task_2]
FROM
 (
  SELECT Course, PersId, TaskId, [Status]
  FROM t2
  ) as a
PIVOT
 (
  MAX([Status])
  FOR TaskId IN ([1], [2])
  ) as b
```

Comment: MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you would have to use a `CASE` and an aggregate function.

Comment: Nobody said that MySQL request is necessary

Comment: the question is tagged as MySQL

Comment: Sorry I new in portal, but question is tagged SQL too))